# How to use a Swagger UI plugin?

Tags: flask, swagger-ui

I am working on a project that, among other things, automatically generates Swagger APIs for Python projects. One thing that I have noticed is that the `curl` text exposes passwords if the API requires those. Since there's no way to mask the passwords as of now (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5025), it seems like the easiest thing to do is to simply disable the `curl` text so that I can screenshare my Swagger API without exposing my password.

In another issue (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5020), a plugin is shown that can disable the curl text.

However, I'm totally stumped on how to actually import and use this plugin. There's lots of documentation about how to write plugins, and none on how to import them. I can see that I can load plugins using the plugins option in https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/, but I don't know how where to put the code.

Comment: Do you use Swagger UI's standalone [`dist` assets](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist), or is Swagger UI bundled with your Python framework/library? If the latter, what framework/library do you use - FastAPI, Flask, etc.?

Comment: I'm using flask-swagger-ui

Comment: I solved it by overwriting index.template.html in flask_swagger_ui/templates

Answer (score 2):

As Helen alludes to, the answer to your question depends on your setup. However, I would hazard to guess that you will need to configure the `SwaggerUI` object by running an "unbundled" version of the app. You might think of this as creating a custom `entrypoint` to a docker container, say.

For example, the [link you provide](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5020) shows suggestions for running a customised version of `SwaggerUI`. Those customisations are written in JavaScript, so any old HTML page with the necessary dependencies in place which loads the script you write to configure `SwaggerUI` would answer the question of "where to put that code".

The details would depend on any frameworks you are or are not using.